# ¿Cómo crear nuevos attributos html con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que deseo saber es como utilizar un atributo para poder ejecutar cualquier método en HTML en cualquier parte que lo use, como lo hacen las librerias. Por ejemplo si deseo usar un atributo HTML llamado "a-toUpperCase" en cualquier etiqueta que contenga texto lo convierta en mayuscula:

```
<p a-toUpperCase>Hola Mundo</p>
```

Alguien me podría decir en cómo hacerlo o darme una referencia por favor, he buscado por todos lados pero nada que sirva.

PD: Todo debe ser JavaScript puro

Comment: ¿Te refieres a los atributos `data` o puede ser de cualquier otra forma, por ejemplo una clase?

Comment: Es mucho menos código, y mas fácil de entender si se hace en CSS. Tan solo le asignas una clase y la declaras en el css de la manera q quieras.

Answer (score 5):

puedes hacerlo asi:

> en el arreglo `fun` debes agregar los metodos de acuerdo a su nombre real.
>   ya que buscara en todo el documento los tag y los cambiara.

```js
   // selector de elementos
var $ = (s) => document.querySelectorAll(s);
// crear otros metodos
String.prototype.red=function(e)  {
return `<span style="color:red;">${this}<span>`;
}
// arreglo contenedor de funciones de tipo cadena
var fun = ["toUpperCase","toLowerCase","bold","italics","red","sup","sub","strike","small","big"];

// recorre el arreglo 
for(let s of fun){
    // busca elementos que contenga a-"tipo de funcion" a-bold, a-small etc.. y hace un recorrido de todos
    for(let x of $(`*[a-${s}]`)){
       // eval() evalua el string que se le pasa y lo combierte a funcion y la ejecuta
        let e = eval(`'${x.innerText}'.${s}()`);
        // agrega el resultado a elemento con el respectivo tag
        x.innerHTML = e;
    }
}
```

```html
<p a-toLowerCase>TEXTO A MINUSCULA</p>
<p a-toUpperCase>texto a mayuscula</p>
<p a-bold>TEXTO A NEGRITA</p>
<p a-italics>TEXTO A ITALICS</p>
<p a-sup>TEXTO A SUP</p>
<p a-sub>texto a sub</p>
<p a-small>texto a small</p>
<p a-big>texto a big</p>
<p a-strike>texto a strike</p>
<p a-toUpperCase a-bold a-strike>texto a mayuscula negrita y strike</p>
<p a-red>texto rojo</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacerlo con sólo Javascript sería asignando un atributo `class` a los elementos, luego con `querySelectorAll` agrupas todos los elementos de una clase y le asignas a cada uno dentro de un `forEach` el estado deseado: MAYÚSCULAS, minúsculas, color..., etc.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var allUpper = document.querySelectorAll('.a-toUpperCase');
allUpper.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.toUpperCase();
});


var allLower = document.querySelectorAll('.a-toLowerCase');
allLower.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.toLowerCase();
});


var allRed = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
allRed.forEach(function(elem) {
  var color = elem.className.split(' ')[1]
  elem.style.color = color;
});
```

```html
<p class="a-toUpperCase">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="a-toLowerCase">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="color red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="color green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="color blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="color orange">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

> **NÓTESE**  que esto ser haría mucho más fácil mediante el manejo de clases CSS, sería cuestión de poner la clase al elemento y CSS haría
>   el resto.

Comment: Desea añadir nuevos atributos html no utilizar atributos existentes como classes

Comment: @Bryro, no lo entendí así en un principio. Supongo que el OP hizo la pregunta por curiosidad, pues tal implementación sería ignorar funcionalidades que ya existen y tratar de reinventar la rueda.

Comment: Futuras referencias! Recurrimos a stackoverflow para despejar una duda o aclarar un tema. principalmente soy de los que lo usa a diario e imagine que tal vez la pregunta venia a raiz de usar una libreria como angular y sus `ng-`

Comment: Puede ser, pero la no referencia a Angular o a cualquiera otra librería y por otra parte las etiquetas `javascript` y `html` en la pregunta pueden hacer pensar que la forma mejor de resolver esto sería mediante clases y CSS. Si ya se considera una mala práctica aplicar estilos *in line*  sobre los elementos HTML, no te digo nada sobre inventar nuevas etiquetas para formatear contenido...